# how to get a menu bar, horizontal row of buttons, and data grid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm so frustrated.  Coming from C++/MFC/Win API, where I could simply trap the WM_SIZE/OnSize() handler, how do I make this work in WPF.  I want a horizontal menu bar, a single row of buttons, and then a datagrid.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Black" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <MenuItem Header="_Data" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit"  Background="Black" Foreground="White"  Click="App_Exit_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Client" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
                <MenuItem Header="_New"  Background="Black" Foreground="White"  Click="New_Client_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="NewClient" Width="80" Height="80" Content="New" Foreground="White"  Click="New_Client_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF141420" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF203060" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Sync" Width="80" Height="80" Content="Sync" Foreground="White"  Click="New_Client_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF141420" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF203060" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="414"/>
    </StackPanel>


</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what issue exactly you are facing? For the layout it seems to be okay.

Comment: I want the DataGrid to fill up the remaining space in the MainWindow

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataGrid` has a fixed `Height`, so it cannot take up the remaining space in your window. Moreover, the surrounding `StackPanel` will measure its children with positive infinity, which causes them to size to the smallest size that fits their content and that is the opposite of what you want.

You just have dock the button bar to the top. The last element, which is the `DataGrid`, will fill the remaining space by default in a `DockPanel`. I have removed the redundant attributes that are set by default in the code below.

```
<DockPanel>
   <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
      <MenuItem Header="_Data" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
         <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Background="Black" Foreground="White" Click="App_Exit_Click"/>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem Header="_Client" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
         <MenuItem Header="_New" Background="Black" Foreground="White" Click="New_Client_Click"/>
      </MenuItem>
   </Menu>
   <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button x:Name="NewClient" Width="80" Height="80" Content="New" Foreground="White" Click="New_Client_Click">
         <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
               <GradientStop Color="#FF141420" Offset="0"/>
               <GradientStop Color="#FF203060" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
         </Button.Background>
      </Button>
      <Button x:Name="Sync" Width="80" Height="80" Content="Sync" Foreground="White" Click="New_Client_Click">
         <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
               <GradientStop Color="#FF141420" Offset="0"/>
               <GradientStop Color="#FF203060" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
         </Button.Background>
      </Button>
   </StackPanel>
   <DataGrid/>
</DockPanel>
```